# Can't disable field indexing on ElasticSearch AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm using AWS ElasticSearch 7.9. I'm pushing logs to it with Filebeat 7.12 installed on an Elastic Beanstalk AMI2.

My log structure is as follow:

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2021-04-07T22:58:08.012Z",
  "label": "My API",
  "level": "info",
  "module": "server",
  "message": "API is starting in production mode. Version 2.74.0",
  "metadata": {
    "foo": {
      "bar": "anything"
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is for ElasticSearch to stop indexing the `metadata` field as it can be litteraly anything. It is used for debug purpose when logging arbitrary objects.

I tried to update the templates (ecs ans filebeat) on ElasticSearch with the API by adding an explicit declaration for the field

```json
"mappings" : {
    "_meta" : {
        "beat" : "filebeat",
        "version" : "7.12.0"
    },
    "properties" : {
        "metadata": {
            "type": "object",
            "enabled": false
        },
...
```

My filebeat configuration:

```yaml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/web.stdout.log
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["https://somurl.es.amazonaws.com:443"]
  username: "username"
  password: "password"
  index: "my_api-filebeat-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

setup.template.name: "filebeat"
setup.template.pattern: "filebeat-*"
setup.template.append_fields:
- name: metadata
  type: object
  enabled: false

setup.ilm.enabled: false
```

However the field `metadata` keeps getting indexed and I end up with a lot of pointless indexes and of course, conflicts, because some fields doesn't have the same type on two logs.

Is there something I'm not doing right ?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track but such an update call would be considered [**a breaking change**](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/1e610596eb5277b07c0cdb8997eb00c8bd177a92/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/mapper/ObjectMapper.java#L485) raising the exception `the [enabled] parameter can't be updated for the object mapping [metadata]`.

At the same time, individual mapping attributes cannot be removed so an effort to copy the old metadata into a new, temporary field, then remove the original field mapping, and then copy the temporary contents back to the original, yet updated `metadata` field would be futile…

**The only option is thus to create a new index with the `enabled: false` attribute, reindex your logs into that new index, and reroute the upcoming log streams to the new index.**

Comment: So if I understand, what you're suggesting is not to update the index template but to create an index manually with the desired mapping, then use this index name in the filebeat config `output.elasticsearch.index` ? Won't that create problems with rolling indexes like I have with `%{+yyyy.MM.dd}`. And also, will I have to do this every time a new Filebeat client wants to connect to the ElasticSearch ? (We use microservices)

Comment: What I like in the way it's made right now is that the Filebeat client can define his index name himself. And it is created automatically. But for now, it's like the index templates configured in ElasticSearch are ignored. Still, I do have the metadata defined in them.

Comment: Keep using the filebeat templates, that's fine. What I'm saying is, retroactively applying a breaking mapping change won't work... TBH I don't have too much experience with rolling indices so I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: After some time away from it, I finally found what was causing the issue.

In my filebeat config I was using the index pattern `my_api-filebeat-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}` which was not recognized by elasticsearch, as the index pattern for the default templates is `filebeat-*`.

Just renaming my index pattern to `filebeat-my_api-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}` in my filebeat config file worked like a charm !